# Проблема с записью массива из файла в C++

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Я ещё очень плохо разбираюсь в работе с файлами в CPP. Мне нужно считать матрицу (Считаем, что размерность известна) из текстового файла.
Вот мой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream matrix("C:\\Users\\Pavel\\Desktop\\cpp1\\matrix.txt");
    float a[60][60];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= 60; j++)
            matrix >> a[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        for (int j = 0; i < 60; i++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа считывает только первое число из файла и записывает его в только (!) первую строчку моего массива. При выводе программа выдаёт только эту первую строку с одним и тем же числом.
Как мне записать весь файла в массив, а потом вывести его без проблем?

Comment: В коде проблемы не  видно, попробуйте оставить в файле только целые числа,  возможно проблема в десятичном разделителе

Comment: @pavel Я уже пытался изменять числа в файле на целые. Менял разделители с . на , но так ничего и не помогло.

Comment: @pavel Хочу добавить, что сам файл не слишком хорошо составлен. Но это не касается первой и второй строки, так как я их отформатировал. У меня там местами два пробела (Массив 60х60, поэтому сложно) возникают. Начало выглядит так: 31.0 11.0 4.2 2.1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

Comment: @pavel Я сейчас изменил первое число на 310. Первая ячейка массива выдала 310, а остальные - 31.

Comment: На пробелы и перевод строк данному коду все равно.  Попробуйте сначала 2 на 2 матрицу прочитать.

Comment: @pavel Создал новый файл. 2х2 - мне вернуло снова только первую строку.

Comment: Ради проверки напишите все в 1 строке, через пробел т.е. без переводов строк

Comment: @pavel только два первых символа выдаёт даже в этом случае.

Comment: Блин... Знак <= замените на < в цикле)

Comment: @pavel Выдало три числа. Третье, похоже, оказалось границей типа float.

Comment: @pavel Ой, я не то сделал. Заменил теперь, как Вы сказали. Выдаёт два числа. Первое и третье.

Comment: @pavel Я сделал, как Вы сказали, но уже с первым массивом. Мне выдало правильно первую строку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45230/discussion-between-pavelkas-and-pavel).

Comment: Очень похоже, что в первых двух циклах неправильное условие. Нужно i < 60, а не <=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки:
1. Строгое неравенство (используйте `<` вместо `<=`).
2. Забыли вычитать пробел, который записали в файл.

Исправленный вариант:

```
void resolve()
{
    bool isFillFromFile = false;    //true для чтения из файла
    int a[60][60];

    if (isFillFromFile)
    {
        std::ifstream ist("matrix.txt");
        char ch;
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)    // ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ НЕ СТРОГОЕ НЕРАВЕНСТВО!!!
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
                ist >> a[i][j] >> ch;   // НЕ ЗАБЫВАЙТЕ ВЫЧИТЫВАТЬ ПРОБЕЛ!!!
    }
    else
    {                                   // Первоначальная генерация файла
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 60; j++)
                a[i][j] = i + j;
    }


    std::ofstream ost("matrix.txt", std::ios_base::trunc);
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        for (int j = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            ost << a[i][j] << " ";      // ЗАПИСЬ ПРОБЕЛА В ФАЙЛ
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }

    ost.close();
}
```